Why are Klein geometries flat?
A Klein geometry can be seen as a principal $H$-bundle of the form $G\to G/H$. It is known (cf. Sharpe and Chern's book) that Klein geometries are examples of flat Cartan geometries because their Cartan connection (the Maurer-Cartan form) is flat. This seems to contradict my understanding that the existence of a flat connection on a principal bundle is equivalent to that bundle having an atlas with locally constant transition functions. Clearly the latter isn't true for most Klein geometries (e.g. the Hopf bundle). Where is the disconnect?

The Maurer-Cartan form is not a principal connection (at least not on the bundle $G\to G/H$), there is no horizontal subspace. The statement that these are flat only makes real sense after one has introduced the general concept of Cartan geometries. Then $G/H$ is flat as a Cartan geometry of type $(G,H)$ and indeed flatness of such a Cartan geometry is equivalent to being locally isomorphic (as a Cartan geometry) to $G\to G/H$.
For example, any homogeneous Riemannian manifold (say a symmetric space) can serve as the homogeneous model for a Cartan geometry. But this does not imply that such a manifold is flat in the Riemannian sense (which can also be equivalently described in the picture of a Cartan geometry). Formally speaking, given a homomgeneous Riemannian manifold $G/H$ of dimension $n$, one always has $H\subset O(n)$ and one can use this to extend the flat Cartan geometry $G\to G/H$ of type $(G,H)$ to a Cartan geometry of type $(Euc(n),O(n))$ (where $Euc(n)$ is the group of rigid motions) that equivalently encodes the Riemannian metric, but this Cartan geometry is not flat in general. (Roughly speaking, flatness of the extended Cartan geometry is equivalent to the fact that the inclusion $H\to O(n)$ extends to an immersive homomorphism $G\to Euc(n)$.

Thank you Andreas!
